# Dead links in the "Attribution Required" blog post need to be fixed

Tags: support, broken-link, blog

I recently visiting the [Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) post on the Stack Overflow blog and found that this content is too old and needed to change. Some urls

1. http://hiveminds.se/vote/framed/story.php?id=23472
2. http://programmingfaq.w3ec.com/

are not working.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the context of those links.  The links are stated as being scammy sites copying content without proper attribution.  That they no longer exist is of course to be expected, and there really isn't any reason or need to follow the links, even when they *were* valid links.

There's nothing for the links to be changed to, as those sites really are gone, and there's no reason to remove them, because it's still important to make the point that there were specific sites doing exactly what was being claimed and inappropriately copying content.  So all in all, there's no reason to change anything, other than, maybe, if you *really* feel the need to do something, to add a notation that they no longer exist.

Comment: *and there really isn't any reason or need to follow the links, even when they were valid links.* Not so sure about that.  I naturally want to click on them to see what it looked like.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure, but that doesn't mean  you *need* to, it just means you might want to.  It's *supplementary* to the point of the blog (at most, and really it's just there for idle curiosity), not vital to the point it's making.

Comment: I don't *need* to but it would be nice to see what he is talking about.  I don't see why we couldn't add newer examples or just use archive.org links.

Comment: @NathanOliver So you agree with the statement in my answer that it's not needed.  Great.  Editing this constantly to put in new links as the old ones continually die is just wasting people's time for something that's not adding any value.

Comment: So lets use archive.org and link to the archived pages and were done.  The author provided the examples for a reason so we should probably keep them if we can (which we can).

Comment: @NathanOliver And what is that accomplishing?  What have we gained from doing that, other than your own personal curiosity being able to be satisfied with 5 seconds less effort than before?

Comment: I just simply say, like we remove the questions and answers that are `off-topic` or not related to SO, we should remove those dead links too.

Comment: @urfusion Questions and answers that are off topic to SO are actively harmful to leave around.  These links are not actively helpful; removing them entirely detracts from those posts (not significantly, but slightly).  Not all dead links are equal.